How to change Zustand storage from sessionStorage to localStorage or back based on the user selection
I need to be able to change Zustand storage at runtime, is it possible?
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { persist, createJSONStorage } from 'zustand/middleware'

export const useBearStore = create(
  persist(
    (set, get) => ({
      bears: 0,
      addABear: () => set({ bears: get().bears + 1 }),
    }),
    {
      name: 'food-storage', // name of the item in the storage (must be unique)
      storage: createJSONStorage(() => sessionStorage), // (optional) by default, 'localStorage' is used
    },
  ),
)


I found an answer, though, this is not good enough for my use case. I want to know where the last time the user persisted its state so that I can load it from there on state creation.
https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data#setoptions
